# representation of the elements in compositum of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

For fields E and F, is the every element of EF, compositum of E and F, could be represented by the finite combination(addition, multiplication, inverse) of the finite element in E and F?

Comment: When $F$ is algebraic over $E$  (or $E$ over $F$) then the ring $EF=\{ \sum_{j=1}^J e_jf_j,e_j\in E,f_j\in F\}$ is a field. When it is not you should better use the notation $EF$ for the ring generated by $E,F$ and $E(F)$ or $Frac(EF)$ for the field.